# Codeigniter XSS filter removing inline style on post Ajax data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, xss

I have a admin panel in codeignter. I have enabled global XSS filtering in application/config/config.php because I need it all the time.

I have a form to add email templates. When i trying to post email template html content XSS filter removes all style attribute from posted content.
I also tried

```
$temptate_body = $this->input->post('temptate_body', FALSE);
```

When i globally disabled XSS filter it works fine but i don't want to disable it globally.

Form is posting through Jquery AJAX. So i also googled to encode the template body content as like PHP htmlentities function does, but not luck.

Any ideas how to disable this behavior so that the site admins will be able to easily assign inline styles to email templates?

Comment: could bypass `$_POST` and send as json content type in body of request

Answer (score 3):

You could read the raw input data in order to bypass the filter, but you shouldn't do that.

The 'global_xss_filtering' setting does automatic XSS filtering on *input*, which is a bad practice and that's why this feature is DEPRECATED in CodeIgniter 3.

Don't enable global XSS filtering; escape everything manually *on output*; and please, unless that form of yours is in the admin panel and you really trust its source, don't just skip escaping because it strips the style attribute. The attribute is stripped because it is potentially dangerous.